# Deleting Duplicates from Multiple Tables in a GeoDatabase

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I'm having trouble deleting duplicates from multiple tables in a geodatabase.  I have a field "facility_id" which should be unique, but I have multiple entries and need to delete all but one.  I've started a python script to delete the duplicates but I'm not sure how to finish it.  I tried a for loop to find all facility_ids in the values list and check for membership in the duplicate values list, but when I use cursor.deleteRow, nothing happens.

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

targetDB = r"C:\data\Temp\436e0250ef1748af92e7f1f75b5a0deb.gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace = targetDB
for table in arcpy.ListTables():
newTable = arcpy.Describe(table).basename
    if "ATTACH" not in newTable:
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(newTable, "facility_id") as cursor:
            values = [r[0] for r in cursor]
            duplicates = [value for value in values if values.count(value) > 1]
            print "Original Table Values: " + str(newTable) + ": " + str(values)
            print "Duplicate Table Values: " + str(newTable) + ": " + str(duplicates)
            if values in duplicates:
                cursor.deleteRow()
```

output:

Original Table Values: ElecConduit: [u'PS145', u'PS022', u'PS022', u'PS108', u'PS134', u'PS999']

Duplicates Table Values: ElecConduit: [u'PS022', u'PS022']

Original Table Values: ElecLighting: [u'PS108', u'PS108', u'PS108']

Duplicates Table Values: ElecLighting: [u'PS108', u'PS108', u'PS108']

Comment: @Jim's code below is a good solution. Cursors as I understand them are typically read once then you need to reset them. As I read your code you have "used up" your cursor to populate the list `values`. Then you try to use it later to delete a row but you have already passed through the entire cursor. This is probably why your code is not working? Jim's code only ever passes through it once so its a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's great that you're using list comprehensions as part of this task, but if I were to run into this same situation, I'd probably want to dumb the script down to a more explicit, step-by-step state. The following changes should delete all duplicate rows for any given *'facility_id'* past the first occurrence of a unique *'facility_id'* value, across all tables not named "ATTACH" in your target .gdb:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

targetDB = r"C:\data\Temp\436e0250ef1748af92e7f1f75b5a0deb.gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace = targetDB
duplicate_check_list = [] # this is a global list recording known facility_id values for duplicate value checking purposes
for table in arcpy.ListTables():
    newTable = arcpy.Describe(table).basename
        if "ATTACH" not in newTable:
            with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(newTable, "facility_id") as cursor:
                for row in cursor:
                    if row[0] in duplicate_check_list: # check the current facility_id against the values already present in the list
                        cursor.deleteRow()
                    else:
                        duplicate_check_list.append(row[0])
```

Best Luck with this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jim.  I'll take a look at it later today and let you know what happens.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, the case your various text variables are in could be a problem. You can fix that by making everything the same case.  For example, instead of if "ATTACH" not in newTable, put if "ATTACH" not in newTable.upper(). Since your facility_id is text, you could do the same thing with the duplicate list, if it is a problem.

Comment: @Jim Thanks again.  I've noticed a bug with the script though.  The duplicate_check_list contains the facility_ids from all of the different tables, so when I walk through each table, if the facility_id was added to the duplicate_check_list from an earlier table, it deletes the row in the subsequent table.  Does that make sense?  It's ok for what I'm doing now because I've changed facility_id to a GlobalID ,but it's just something I noticed.

Comment: @user7278 - You are absolutely correct, the duplicate_check_list persists and affects all tables in the stack; based on the original question I went ahead and assumed this was the desired effect. To change this behavior to *only check for duplicates in the context of one table at a time, not global,* you could move the `duplicate_check_list = []` variable declaration to sit between the opening of your `with` statement and the start of the `for row in cursor:` loop. Good catch!